# How should a textbook structure its answer key to minimise contamination of the student's memory?

Tags: books

I read many textbooks (mainly multichoice questions or short answers) and they seem to put all the answers together and that seems bad because the student can't do a section without seeing the answers and there having their memory and therefore learning contaminated. Is there a best way to structure the answers arrangement within or auxiliary the textbook (a website could do it better but refering to website is limiting)?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of listing the answers (in an appendix) in numerical order (answer 1, answer 2, answer 3, ...), the answers could be listed in mixed order (answer 10, answer 4, answer 7, ...). The location of the answer would then be noted along with the question.  (For example, in the text of Question 1, add the note "The answer to Question 1 is on page 102.")  This is what is done in some puzzle books or magazines.

Comment: Love how simple this is. Naturally dissuading the user from reading more than the answer they came for.